# How can i find the index of the first alphabet of second last word in a string

Tags: regex, string, kotlin

I want to find index from string. How can i find the index of the first alphabet of second last word in a string.

```
 val index = "Hey! How are you men? How you doing"
```

i want to search **you doing** from the above string, but i want **y** index from the word **you**. I did some code to find index but I am unable to find it.

```
fun main(vararg args: String) {
    val inputString = "Hey! How are you men? How you doing"
    val regex = "you doing".toRegex()
    val match = regex.find(inputString)!!
    println(match.value)
    println(match.range)
}
```

Comment: yeah i guess this

Comment: Instead of [_alphabet_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alphabet#Noun), do you mean _letter_ or _[alphabetic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alphabetic#Adjective) character_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex finds the last two words in your sentence and calculates the index by subtracting the length of the two words from the length of the string.

```
val result = Regex("^(?:.*?\\s+)?([^\\s]+\\s+[^\\s]+)$").matchEntire(inputString)
if (result != null) {
    println(inputString.length - result.groupValues[1].length)
} else {
    println("not supported")
}
```

Supports inputs like

```
Hey! How are you men? How you doing
Hey! How are you men? How you doing?
Hey! How are you, John?
Hello there!
```

Comment: can you explain what groupValues[1].lenght do?

Comment: also please "^.*?\s+(\w+\s+\w+[!?.]?$)" what this means? @Daniel

Comment: I tweaked the answer a bit to be more robust. Basically the regex matches the last two sets of consecutive non-space characters in the string that are separated by space. It puts the segment in to a match group due to the parenthesis around `([^\\s]+\\s+[^\\s]+)`. `groupValues[1]` retrieves the matched string within the `(...)`.

Comment: what this **^.*?** means?

Comment: `^` marks the beginning of string. `.` means any character. `*` means zero or more of such character (in this case zero or more of any character. `?` here means the previous zero or more should be non-greedy. You should be able to find more detailed information about regex by Googling regex tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

[Split](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) the string, then take the first character of the second-to-last element of the resulting array.

Comment: i think it not a good way

Comment: Why do you think that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the index of the `y` in `you doing` related to the entire string (`Hey! How are you men? How you doing`), you can use `indexOf`.

```
val inputString = "Hey! How are you men? How you doing"
val matchString = "you doing"
val matchIndex = inputString.indexOf(matchString)
```

[More info on `indexOf` here.](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/index-of.html)

Comment: Is there any other way to find other words from inputString also without matchString?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do or match on? If you're just trying to get the index of where a word or phrase starts, you could split the string, then use the split array to get the indexOf.

Comment: I am getting the string randomly. I always want to find the index of the first alphabet of second last word in a string without match string.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a regex (which you probably shouldn't unless you need the efficiency) the simplest option is probably what @samuei says:

```
index.split(' ').takeLast(2).first().first()
```

(take the last two words, take the first of those, and then the first character of that)

If you want to mess with indices instead you could do this kind of thing:

```
val lastSpaceIndex = index.lastIndexOf(' ')
val secondToLastSpace = index.lastIndexOf(' ', startIndex = lastSpaceIndex -1)
println(index.get(secondToLastSpace + 1))
```

where you're finding the index of the last space, then the index of the last space *before* that one, and then grabbing the character after that. But this is already getting a lot less readable, and is it worth the extra complexity? Your call!